# Velocity: Keep carriage returns and tabs

Tags: velocity

I'm using Velocity and JavaMail with spring to create mails for a Java app.

I save a Hibernate @Lob in database.

My clob is saved with carriage returns and tabulations in db:

[image: img1]

but when I receive the mail my text is not formatted anymore:

[image: img2]

My code is quite simple:

```
Map model = new HashMap();
model.put("monitoringError", baseMonitoringError);
model.put("businessCode", businessCode);
String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "velocity/crashMailTemplate.vm", "UTF-8", model);
```

from the template:

```
<p><strong>Stacktrace:</strong></p>
    <p><em><span class="crayon-i ">${monitoringError.stacktrace}</span>    </em></p>
```

...and the baseMonitoringError bean is a Hibernate Entity with

```
@Lob
@Column
private String stacktrace;
```

How should I do to keep the formatted original text?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
${monitoringError.stacktrace.replace("\n","<br/>")}
```

or, depending on your platform:

```
${monitoringError.stacktrace.replace("\r\n","<br/>")}
```